# tar -xvf file.tar.gz failed with: gzip:stdin:not in gzip format

Tags: gzip, tar

I tar a set of files with command:`tar -czvf file.tar.gz file/` then copy to usb (ext4 format), I checked that I can untar it. After I reinstall system , when mount usb , some error happened , I do `fsck /dev/sdc1` and success in mount and copy it to pc. When I untar it `tar -xvf file.tar.gz`, error happen again:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar : child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have no idea how to rescue the data.
Any help needed. Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 8):

@sitexa , I got this error when file is not fully downloaded(transferred).

```
tar xvfz apache-tomcat-8.5.12.tar.gz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

This error is coming due to file is not completely downloaded.

reference : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1319801

Comment: Not until I saw this answer did I realize my wget output was showing my JDK download was only 4kb.

Answer (score 0):

check for file by the command

```
file <file name>

<filename>: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines
```

comes then it may be corrupted

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer